# Puntero a struct en ansi C

Tags: c, punteros, struct

Tengo definido lo siguien globalmente.

```
char   buffer[32+1];
TOKEN  tokenActual;
int    flagToken = 0;

typedef enum{
  INICIO, FIN, LEER, ESCRIBIR, ID, CONSTANTE, PARENIZQUIERDO, PARENDERECHO,
  PUNTOYCOMA, COMA, ASIGNACION, SUMA, RESTA, FDT, ERRORLEXICO
}TOKEN;

typedef struct{
  TOKEN clase;
  char  nombre[32+1];
  int   valor;
}T_REG;

T_REG TS[1000] = {{INICIO,   "inicio",   99},
                  {FIN,      "fin",      99},
                  {LEER,     "leer",     99},
                  {ESCRIBIR, "escribir", 99},
                  {99,       "$",        99}};
```

y dentro del main tengo esta función:

```
TOKEN ProximoToken(){
  T_REG *reg;
  tokenActual = scanner(); /*scanner analiza un flujo, devuelve un TOKEN y en buffer almacena lo analizado*/
  if(tokenActual == ID) Buscar(buffer, TS, reg);
  printf("*** Encontre nombre[%s] clase[%d]\n", reg->nombre, reg->clase);
  return tokenActual;
}
```

y Buscar:

```
int Buscar(char *id, T_REG *TS, T_REG *reg){
  int i = 0;
  while(strcmp("$", TS[i].nombre)){
    if(!strcmp(id, TS[i].nombre)){
      reg = &TS[i];
      printf("*** Buscar: nombre[%s] clase[%d]\n", reg->nombre, reg->clase);
      return 1;
    }
    i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Mi problema es que cuando llamo a "Buscar" le paso buffer="inicio", lo busca en TS y cuando lo encuentra me imprime en pantalla:

```
*** Buscar: nombre[inicio] clase[0]
```

El tema es que cuando termina Buscar y vuelvo a ProximoToken, yo entiendo que "reg" apunta a una posición en TS. Y cuando pretendo imprimir en pantalla los valores de ese struct apuntado, imprime basura.

Que estoy haciendo mal?

Aclaro que esto es parte de un "seudo compilador" que analiza un archivo con codigo y lo evalua. Por ejemplo:

```
inicio
  leer (a,b);
  cc := a + (b-2);
  escribir (cc, a+4);
fin
```

---

tengo una funcion que devuelve un punto a puntero:

```
T_REG** Colocar(char *id, T_REG *TS){
  T_REG **reg;
  int i = 4;
  while(strcmp("$", TS[i].nombre)) i++;
  if(i < 999){
    strcpy(TS[i].nombre, id);
    TS[i].clase = ID;
    TS[i].valor = 0;
    *reg = &TS[i];
    strcpy(TS[++i].nombre, "$");
    return reg;
  }
}
```

Esta funcion pretende agregar un identificador a la lista TS y devolver un puntero a ese elemento agregado.

en `*reg = &TS[i];` revienta. porque? los punteros a punteros se tiene que inicializar? si pregunto `if(*reg == NULL)` tmb revienta

Comment: Aquí falta información... ¿Qué código tiene el `main()`?

Comment: son 400 lineas de codigo, no tiene sentido que lo pegue todo. No es un error de compilacion, es un error de concepto que tengo.

Comment: claro eso me acabo de dar cuenta. Imprime esto:
`*** Buscar: nombre[inicio] clase[0]`
`*** Encontre nombre[No se pudo abrir archivo de salida.] clase[119]`

Ahora la duda que tengo es, TS es un array global. Porque estaria fuera de hambito??

Comment: No es `TS`, es el puntero que utilizas para pasarlo... Prueba a cambiar la definición de `Buscar` por `Buscar(char *, T_REG *, T_REG **reg);` y en la asignación cambia por `*reg = &TS[i];`

Comment: Ahi esta, hice exactamente eso!
`int Buscar(char *id, T_REG *TS, T_REG **reg)`
Mil gracias!!

Comment: Ahí te dejo una respuesta para que la marques si consideras :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema básicamente es que pasas solo el puntero, si el puntero es NULL, la asignación se completa, pero nunca se devuelve a `ProximoToken`.

Te recomiendo cambiar la firma de la función `Buscar` por la siguiente:

```
int Buscar(char *id, T_REG *TS, T_REG **reg);
```

Haces la asignación dentro de la función de la siguiente forma:

```
*reg = &TS[i];
```

Y al llamar la función, recuerda pasar la dirección del puntero que necesitas:

```
Buscar(id, TS, &reg);
```

Arreglado tu código luciría de la siguiente forma:

```
int Buscar(char *id, T_REG *TS, T_REG **reg){
  int i = 0;
  while(strcmp("$", TS[i].nombre)){
    if(!strcmp(id, TS[i].nombre)){
      *reg = &TS[i];
      printf("*** Buscar: nombre[%s] clase[%d]\n", reg->nombre, reg->clase);
      return 1;
    }
    i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

De esta forma pasas la dirección del puntero en `reg` y haces que la dirección cambie cuando sea necesaio si se encuentra el token.

**Edit: En respuesta a tu nuevo problema**

En esta linea:

```
T_REG **reg;
```

Colocas un puntero a puntero, pero nunca colocas memoria para utilizar dicho puntero, puedes utilizar dos formas:

```
T_REG *reg;
```

Y realizar una asignacion normal de puntero para luego retornarlo:

```
reg = &TS[i];
```

O bien puedes colocar memoria dinámica (En *heap*) para utilizar el puntero:

```
T_REG **reg = malloc(sizeof(T_REG *));
```

Y utilizar la misma asignación:

```
*reg = &TS[i];
```

Tu programa "crashea" porque el puntero a puntero `reg` no está apuntando hacia una dirección de memoria válida (`NULL`) y necesitas, o colocar memoria para usarlo, o cambiarlo a un puntero simple.

Comment: Eso funciono bien, pero me surgio algo.
Para compilar uso MinGW, un gcc para windows. El tema que me surgio es que como necesito compilar con estandar C89, compila pero rompe aca `*reg = &TS[i];` Cuando trata de ejecutar esa sentencia rompe. Si lo compilo asi: `gcc tp.c -o tp.exe` funciona, pero asi: `gcc -std=c89 tp.c -o tp.exe` rompe en esa instruccion. Que puede ser???

Comment: No puedes utilizar otro estandar? Si estas compilando en windows puedes utilizar C11 o C99, de todas formas puedes probar a: `*reg = (TS + i);` y me cuentas que tal

Comment: no, solo estandar 89. Igualmente pasa algo raro, en Buscar funciona bien pero la misma instruccion en otro funcion es la que explota.

Comment: Y pasó algo al utilizar la forma en que te dije?

Comment: edito la pregunta

Comment: Listo, he editado la respuesta para tu problema.

Comment: si, ese era el problema!